# Problems with create_row() function

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo

All,

This javascript code dynamically adds input boxes based on a user's selection of a dropdown box.  I have it almost where it needs to be, but right now, both the "msds_copy" and "cofa_copy" cases display the same data for "html2" when I test.  The "msds_copy" selection should make the 2nd form box say "Region/Language" but instead it's saying "Batch Number".

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
inquiry_type_onchange: function(e) {
        var place_order = 1,
            order_status = 2,
            telalert_signup = 3,
            invoice_questions = 4,
            msds_copy = 5,
            cofa_copy = 6,
            html = null,
            html2 = null,
            inquiry = e.target,
            id = "inquiry_type_addendum",
            form_row = dojo.query("."+id);

        //Clear any possible previous additions. 
        if (form_row != null)
            form_row.forEach(dojo.destroy);

        //Add the correct new field to the form.
        switch (inquiry.selectedIndex) {
            case place_order:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Account Number:");
                break;
            case order_status:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Order Number:");
                break;
            case telalert_signup:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Account Number:");
                break;
            case invoice_questions:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Invoice Number");
                break;
            case msds_copy:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Product Name:");
                html2 = this.create_form_row(id + "_2", "Region / Language:");  
            case cofa_copy:
                html = this.create_form_row(id, "Product Name:");
                html2 = this.create_form_row(id + "_2", "Batch Number:");
            default:
        }

        if (html == null) return;
        //Place the new element below the inquiry_type field. 
        var placeat = dojo.byId('buttons');
        dojo.place(html, placeat, "before");
        if(html2!=null)
            dojo.place(html2, placeat, "before");
    },

    create_form_row: function(id, label) {
        //Container
        var a = dojo.create("div", { id: id, className: "question inquiry_type_addendum", style: "padding-top:4px;" });
        //Label
        var b = dojo.create("div", { className: "label", innerHTML: label, style: "margin-top:8px;" }, a);
        //Field
        var c = dojo.create("div", { className: "field" });
        var d = dojo.create("span", { className: "full_number_span span" });
        var e = dojo.create("input", { type: "text", className: "textbox full_number", name: label }, d);
        dojo.place(d, c);
        dojo.place(c, a);
        return a;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing your `break`s and the switch case `msds_copy` is executing then falling through to the next case `cofa_copy`.

```
        case msds_copy:
            html = this.create_form_row(id, "Product Name:");
            html2 = this.create_form_row(id + "_2", "Region / Language:");  
            break; // <----
        case cofa_copy:
            html = this.create_form_row(id, "Product Name:");
            html2 = this.create_form_row(id + "_2", "Batch Number:");
            break; // <----
```

Comment: Oh wow.  Staring at the screen too long over here!  Thanks so much!